# Does Yig's awakened reckoning effect spawn a cultist on each space fulfilling the requirement, or just 1 on a space of your choice?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore

The reckoning effect is

> Spawn 1 Cultist Monster on a space containing a Mystery token, Eldritch token, or Epic Monster.

Does this mean 1 cultist on each space with any of those items, or 1 cultist on a space of our choice that fulfills the requirement? The literal reading seems to imply the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is language used:

> Spawn 1 Cultist Monster on **a space** containing a Mystery token, Eldritch token, or Epic Monster."

Reads differently to

> Spawn 1 Cultist Monster on **each space** containing a Mystery token, Eldritch token, or Epic Monster."

Thus, the reckoning is to spawn *a single cultist* on any space containing a Mystery token, Eldritch token, or Epic Monster.

Answer (score 2):

"Spawn 1 monster on a space" - you only spawn one cultist, and you, as a group, chose which space will that be if more than 1 option is available.